# Print each character of a word line by line using a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I am giving input word is "hello"

My output will be print as mentioned below using SQL query not pl/sql.

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS that you are using along with its version. E.g `Oracle11g`, `SQL Server 2019` etc.,

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUBSTR()` function within a hierarchical query such as

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col,level,1) AS "letters"
  FROM t
 CONNECT BY level <= LENGTH(col)
```

*presuming your DB is Oracle from the keyword PL/SQL*

Comment: That's going to be horrifyingly slow. Join a tally table with `SUBSTRING` instead

Comment: I think more performance shouldn't be expected from a string operation @Charlieface . We are not able to benefit neither indexes, nor partitions for such operations. Btw, What's `SUBSTRING` in terms of Oracle DB?

Comment: I think it's `SUBSTR`. Using `CONNECT BY` or a recursive CTE is going to be dog slow because it's an RBAR operation, whereas a tally table is set-oriented

Comment: well, do you have an alternative solution @Charlieface ?

Comment: I gave you one: join a tally/numbers table

Comment: @Charlieface you gave me `SUBSTRING` and `tally/numbers table`, and I mentioned about `Oracle DB`, What's the correlation ?

Comment: `SUBSTR` in Oracle. I'm sure an experienced SQLer like you can create a numbers table. You join the numbers table `ON numbers.n <= LEN(string)` and select `SUBSTR(string, n, 1)` this explodes the string into single characters.

Comment: of course that's also possible, but isn't that a redundant way while already this current brief method exists @Charlieface

Comment: I'll leave you to think about the performance implications of using an rCTE (or `CONNECT BY` which is basically the same). Admittedly I only have experience on MSSQL, but I would imagine Oracle is similar

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
select substring(a.b, v.number+1, 1) 
from (select 'hellow' b) a
join master..spt_values v on v.number < len(a.b)
where v.type = 'P'
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention your DBMS, but in Postgres you can use:

```
select *
from unnest(string_to_array('hello', null));
```

Comment: For SQL Server, join on a Tally Table ([Itzik Ben-Gan's here](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/12/t-sql-queries/number-series-challenge)), then select `SUBSTRING('hello', n, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this in oracle

```
select 'hello'  
      ,substr('hello',rownum,1) as vertical_str
  from dual a
  join all_tables b
    on 1=1
where rownum<=length('hello')    

h
e
l
l
o
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is a recursive CTE.

```
WITH
word
(word)
AS
(
SELECT 'hello' word
       FROM dual
),
letter
(letter,
 remainder)
AS
(
SELECT substr(word, 1, 1) letter,
       substr(word, 2) remainder
       FROM word
UNION ALL
SELECT substr(remainder, 1, 1) letter,
       substr(remainder, 2) remainder
       FROM letter
       WHERE remainder IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT letter
       FROM letter;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=34fed7519c6d458f25f30e7d091e6008)

I am assuming Oracle here as you mentioned PL/SQL. But for other DBMS this would be pretty similar -- the `substr()` function might be called `substring()`, instead of a `NULL` you'd have to check for `remainder` to be the empty string and the `RECURESIVE` keyword might be needed for the second CTE.